# You have requested a synthetic service ("kernel"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service

Tags: php, symfony, ezpublish, ibexa

Context :

Using Ibexa 3.3 CMS based on Symfony 5.4
Upgrading to Ibexa 4.0.8.

When compiling the container, I get the message :

```
You have requested a synthetic service ("kernel"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service.
```

I've read that this means it's trying to instantiate a "kernel" service but I don't have any service in my source code that does that